# Design automation v3: pdf Plot doesn't display pdf & image attached

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to plot a dwg with pdf & images attached to it.
Dwgs export well, but images and pdfs attached to it are not visible.

I'm using a custom activity with the PlotEngine.

Is it a problem on the forge side? Or is it possible to fix this bug directly in the AppPackage

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether you have supplied the image file that you attached into the drawing as an input argument? If your input argument only specifies the host drawing file, then the Design Automation does not know where the image is and it will treat it as an unresolved reference. In this case, the image won't be plotted into the PDF.

Comment: All files are well sent.
If I download all the files via the links available in the workitem log and test the same command locally, I have no problem

Comment: Hi Mathieu, can you send me the workitem id (if you know) or your Forge user id through email (qun.lu@autodesk.com) so I can look into the problem further? Thanks.